# Underline under cursor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have implemented Custom edittext, with custom style :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TExtAppearance"
            >

            <com.app.farmtrace.fieldagent.CustomView.EditText_SemiBold
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:theme="@style/EditTextStyle"
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:maxLength="50"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textNoSuggestions"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/password"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And this is the screen :

[image]

there is just the cursor and now when i again select the cursor i get this :

[image]

I dont want the yellow underline below the cursor.

This is tested in Moto g4 with android 7.0.

```
<style name="TExtAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    </style>



<style name="EditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <!--<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>-->
    </style>
```

**Edit**
Also Getting underline on error if i seterror and text not visible of error :

[image]

Comment: @[Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44036429/14357707) Removing Widget.AppCompat.EditText from styles worked!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue. I was able to get rid of the cursor underline by removing the `Widget.AppCompat.EditText` parent style from my `TextInputEditText`s' custom style. In other words, I changed my `TextInputEditText`s' style from this:

```
<style name="MyEditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
        ...
</style>
```

to this:

```
<style name="MyEditTextStyle">
        ...
</style>
```

Example of one of my `TextInputEditText`s referencing the style:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/MyEditTextStyle"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set inputType="textNoSuggestions" your edit text in android

```
     android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: alresy  android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textNoSuggestions" added, check the code i have attached

Comment: Upload your com.app.farmtrace.fieldagent.CustomView.EditText_SemiBold class

Answer (score 0):

try to set background with the help of drawable

make a new drawable file  eg. et_back.xml and make a background/shape

then use it as background in your edit text ...

eg. let it be your drawable.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

and your edittext be :

```
<EditText
    //other attribute/properties
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_name"        
    />
```